# ORA-01019 unable to allocate memory in the user side in ADO program on Windows 7

Tags: oracle, delphi, ado

I converted our Delphi 7 BDE programs to use ADO so they can run on Windows 7.  But I get the error ORA-01019 unable to allocate memory in the user side.  I made myself part of a group with create global object rights and the program runs.  But we do not want to grant the standard user this right.  I also created a customized manifest where the execution level is "requireAdministrator" and placed it in the project folder.  I still get the same error.

Comment: My advice is to forget about ADO/OleDB for using Oracle, and connect via third-party components like http://devart.com/odac or our http://blog.synopse.info/tag/Oracle

Comment: What Oracle client version are you using? Have you connected successfully through SQL Plus on the same computer?

Comment: Please, provide the exact version of Delphi, Oracle and OCI and the line of code where you get the exception. If there is a query or stored procedure envolved, please provide its code too. My experience with OCI tells me that the Oracle implementation is better than M$´s one. I´ve used DevArt ODAC already and it works fine, but I never had any seiour problem with the OLE-DB driver from Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to use Microsoft OLEDB provider for Oracle (`MSDAORA`), Oracle OLEDB provider (`OraOLEDB`) or even Oracle ODBC. One of them should work without adjusting user rights.
2. ADO is not the best choice for Oracle data access. `MSDAORA` uses `OCI7`, and gets number of limitations, like cannot work with BLOB's. `OraOLEDB` uses new OCI, but has some issues too, like fails to edit some query results, etc. Finally ADO (dbGo, more precisely) is slow ([more](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/data-access-performance.html)).
3. Consider to migrate to 3d party products. The BDE -> 3d party way is simple with many data access libraries, including our product - [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) ([more](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Migrating_BDE_applications.html)). Also, they does not have such issues.